# How do I run a command on localhost with saved credentials? -Powershell

Tags: powershell

I want to run one command with saved credentials on powershell, i have the following script

```
$user = "test"
$passwd = ConvertTo-SecureString -String "ExtremelyStrongPassword" -AsPlainText -Force
$cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $user, $passwd
Copy-Item -Path "C:\Temp\*" "C:\Program Files\Test\" -Credentials $cred
```

The user doesn't have administrator permissions, but in the localhost we have an user with administrator permissions to run these process.

The error returned is "Access Denied"

How do i pass these parameters to run a command with elevation?

Comment: Elevating a script is a common thing, with many examples all over the web and in videos. What did you search for? What did you try from tt search? What errors did you encounter with what you tried?

Comment: Don't try to pass security credentials from one account to the other (as this will open a security hole), instead assign the correct (specific) permissions to the required items (such as files).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never pass plain text credentials in a  script. Use the Get-Credential cmdlet to collect and use them. Even doing this, the user will get prompted for a password.

- This is what the -RunAs switch of Start-Process is for
- Or set your script to auto elevate
- Or use the credential switch of a cmdlet
- Or use a scheduled task with whatever creds you need, and let the user run it.
- Use the Requires statement at the top of your script
- Store the need creds in the Windows Credential Store and call them
  from there

[about_Requires - PowerShell | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_requires)

> Short description Prevents a script from running without the required
> elements.

```
#Requires -RunAsAdministrator
```

> [Start-Process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process)
>
> Example 5: Start PowerShell as an administrator This example starts
> PowerShell by using the Run as administrator option.

```
Start-Process -FilePath "powershell" -Verb RunAs
```

Using what you have this way:

```
Copy-Item -Path 'C:\Temp\*' 'C:\Program Files\Test\' -Credentials (Get-Credential -Credential 'Domain\UserName')
```

With exception of the scheduled task approach, each will prompt the user for a password, which sounds like what you wanting to avoid. So, consider the following:

> Accessing Windows Credentials Manager from PowerShell
>
> This simple PowerShell class can be used for working with Credentials
> Manager and Password Vault in Windows: checking if account information
> is present in the vault, saving credentials to the vault and reading
> stored login and password information from the vault.
>
> https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Accessing-Windows-7210ae91
>
> Using the registry to store credentials:
>
> [Save Encrypted Passwords to Registry for PowerShell](https://www.spjeff.com/2016/08/17/save-encrypted-passwords-to-registry-for-powershell)